# G++ -Xlinker --gc-sections removes debug symbols

Tags: c++, linux, linker, gdb, debug-symbols

I am using eclipse to compile an application, and have recently switched toolchains (arm-***-linux-gnueabi-g++ --version == v4.8.3). This toolchain was generated using crosstool-ng.

This new toolchain uses the same version of g++ as the old codesourcery arm-none-linux-gnueabi toolchain I was using, however when I build the application using the same compiler and linker flags, the new toolchain seems to strip out all the debug symbols (except in main.cpp?!), when the codesourcery one did not.

To compile, I am using:

```
arm-***-linux-gnueabi-g++ -mcpu=arm926ej-s -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall  -g3 -ggdb ...
```

and to link:

```
arm-***-linux-gnueabi-g++ -mcpu=arm926ej-s -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall  -g3 -ggdb -Xlinker --gc-sections ...
```

After some investigation I discovered that the debug symbols were being removed by the new linker, and as I had only set one linker flag (-Xlinker --gc-sections), I removed it and when I re-built, all the symbols were included in the binary again.

I basically want to know which of the two compilers I have used is exhibiting the correct behaviour. Should the -Xlinker --gc-sections flag remove debug symbols, or is this a bug in the linker that has been built?

Comment: As far as I know, `--gc-sections` removes unused symbols like functions and variables, not debug symbols. `--gc-sections` requires compiler options `-ffunction-sections` and `-fdata-sections` to track variables and functions so they can be removed during link. Maybe the tool you are using to display symbols and debug information is getting confused; and its output is not accurate. Or maybe, your makefile is calling `strip` to remove the debug information.

Comment: @jww - I've double checked and I'm definitely not calling `strip` anywhere in the Make process. It is definitely the useage of the `--gc-sections` flag that is causing the debug symbols to be removed.

Comment: If you weren't calling `strip` directly, is it possible you were passing the `--strip-all` option to the linker?